# Creating Multiple Ajax / Jquery inline form validations in one .php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, validation

Ok, I am still pretty new to the whole Jquery, Ajax, and PHP side of web design. To be more specific - I am attempting to learn everything all over again after not doing any type of web design for over 10 years lol. I am not looking to have someone write the code for me, all I need is a little push in the right direction. Because I have been searching all over the web to no avail.

What I am attempting to do is create a registration form for my site with multiple inline validations that will validate onBlur.  So far I have been able to get two validations to work correctly (checking if the user name already exists in the MySql DB and the password strength) And I am banging my head against the wall at the moment trying to figure out the most efficient way to create multiple validations in one file. My idea is to check if the user name already exists, if the e-mail already exists - and if it is a valid e-mail, check to see if an account exists with a concatenated string of first name and last name, and if the password and retype password fields match.  I would like the validation results to display to the right of the text box with either a red x or green check.
Thank you for taking the time to read this, I appreciate any type of guidance

Respectfully,
          Paul J. Wesselkamper

Comment: Have you even tried anything yourself?

Comment: With respect, If you had read the message completely before attempting to take someone down a notch to make you feel better about yourself I stated " I am not looking to have someone write the code for me, all I need is a little push in the right direction. Because I have been searching all over the web to no avail."

Comment: I will re-state my original question since it is apparently not in plain enough English. Does anyone know of a good site to find information regarding this particular matter? What I have found and have tried has not worked the way I would like - or I am searching for this incorrectly.

Comment: Why did you want to do all the validation with ajax? If someone turn off Javascript your validation won't work. Instead of JS for validation use your server side validation for all the things.

Comment: I'm still very new in trying to learn, I guess I got tunnel vision only focusing on one avenue of approach not considering of things that could cause problems down the road. I appreciate the push in another direction - I will start to research it in this new light.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it's to simple because it's so easy but I will give it a try:
You could create the ajax requests in your script posting the user input to an PHP-script every time you recognize an user input.
This PHP-script will check the posted data and send back some information, maybe a code.
In JavaScript you receive this code an show the user what's wrong or right.

Note to check all inputs again when you are inserting them into your database.

Comment: It may be simple, and that may be the problem. I am thinking too hard into something that should be an easy solution. But, I am still in the very early stages of picking all this back up after a very long time - and I started getting tunnel vision. Enough of my b.s. excuses lol - I'll give it another look with your help in mind - thank you for taking the time in replying with helpful advice.